# Openlayers: GeoServer WMS layer strange behavior when panning and zooming

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

[image]

As you noticed the image above, during panning and zooming the layer is not reprojected properly. I have applied `tilesorigin` property but still occurs.

```
floodMapCBR = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Near-real Time", geoserver_url, {
        srs: "EPSG:32651",
        layers: "cite:evidensapp_floodhazard",
        format: "image/png8",
        gridSet: "EPSG:4326",
        transparent: !0,
        tiled: !0,
        styles: "cite:Hazard Map",
        tilesorigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
    }, {
        displayInLayerSwitcher: !1
    }, {
       buffer: 0,
        isBaseLayer: !1

    })
```

What causes it?

But when the layer is fully loaded, it is gone(*the layer on the sea*), and it is reprojected properly.

Comment: Do you have your custom projection (EPSG:32651) definition? OpenLayers supports limited set of projections by default, but you can extend that set using proj4js library. Try to include proj4js (note that OpenLayers 2 supports old 1.1.0 version) and add projection definition to the top of your script. Definition can be found here: http://epsg.io/32651 So your definition will look like this: `Proj4js.defs["EPSG:32651"] = "+proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";`

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I don't have. What causes it? What do you mean by adding projection definition? So, it's the projection?

Comment: take out all the SRS references from the layer, it will be filled in (correctly) from the map projection